# MS SQL How to get the next month if its december

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I wanna get the next month in `SQL server` but what if the month is `12`.
when i have `date = '2016-10-04'` then  the next month will be `date = '2016-11-04'`.

I want to put this into this query :

```
if EXISTS(
  select * from month 
  where id_Prod = @id_Prod 
  and datepart(month,DATEADD(month,1,_date)) = datepart(month,DATEADD(month,1,_date)) 
  and datepart(YEAR,_date) = datepart(YEAR,@date)
);
```

Comment: *what if the month is 12.* May be you should answer that question

Comment: Specify what you want to do if the month is 12. Be clear about your requirement first.

Comment: i think should replace this : datepart(YEAR,@date)
by this : datepart(month,DATEADD(YEAR,1,_date))

Comment: Removed the MYSQL tag as it seems quite irrelevant

Comment: So, as input you have a variable? `@date` containing an arbitrary date, and you want to find any rows in the `month` table with a `_date` column value that occurs in the month that follows `@date`? And if we're in December, we should presumably select values from January of next year?

Comment: I can see your problem, if you add 1 to a month, it doesn't add one to the year when it laps round - unless you do YEAR(_date) * 12 + MONTH(_date) = YEAR(@date) * 12 + MONTH(@date) + 1   this term asks if _date is in the calendar month after @date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try dateadd

```
declare @dt date = getdate()

select datepart(MM,dateadd(mm,1, @dt))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the spec I've given in the comments is correct, you want something along the lines of:

```
if EXISTS(
  select * from month 
  where id_Prod = @id_Prod 
  and _date >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',@date),'20010201')
  and _date < DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',@date),'20010301')
);
```

The `DATEADD`,`DATEDIFF` pairs are just being used to generate "the 1st of next month" and "the 1st of the month after that", using arbitrary (fixed) dates to compute those. E.g. the first line computes how many whole months have occurred between 1st January 2001 and `@date`. It then adds that number of months onto 1st February 2001. This expression should therefore always generate the 1st of the month that comes after `@date`. The second pair does the same but adds the computed number onto 1st March instead.

You should also note that I'm not applying any functions to `_date`, so if there happens to be a useful index on that column, it should be usable for this query.

Comment: thank u sir but what abt the year if the month is 12

Comment: @adilzakarya - what of it? I'm computing two dates - one is "the start of next month" and the other is "the start of the month after next". Those computations always work. We don't need to do any special casing for the 12th month of the year, presuming in that circumstance that you want to find values in January of the following year.

Comment: @adilzakarya - and if that's *not* what you want, you might want to consider editing your question and trying to create a clearer specification. Some sample data, expected inputs and outputs would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty simple,

Get Previous date of current date

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) AS PrviousDate
```

Get Next date of current date

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()) AS NextDate
```